# Bug in function message_route of mail.thread Openerp

Tags: message, odoo

Seems to me that one of the default behaviors (i.e. The 3rd attempt to get the message route: "Fallback to the provided parameters, if they work") of .message_route(...) is not working properly.

It is supposed to parse the subject for an expression like [ID] to be used as 'thread_id' to post the message. So far, so good.

The problem is that the message is being parsed (of course) in .message_parse(...) before getting to this point, which makes that, when getting the 'thread_id' this way, we end up with a unicode-string instead of the required #ID as integer or long.

Am I right or am I missing something here?

```
def message_route(self, cr, uid, message, model=None, thread_id=None,
                  custom_values=None, context=None):
[...]
    3. Fallback to the ``model``, ``thread_id`` and ``custom_values``
       provided.
[...]
# 3. Fallback to the provided parameters, if they work
    if not thread_id:
         # Legacy: fallback to matching [ID] in the Subject
         match = tools.res_re.search(decode_header(message, 'Subject'))
         thread_id = match and match.group(1)
     assert thread_id and hasattr(model_pool, 'message_update') or hasattr(model_pool, 'message_new'), \
         "No possible route found for incoming message with Message-Id %s. " \
         "Create an appropriate mail.alias or force the destination model." % message_id
     if thread_id and not model_pool.exists(cr, uid, thread_id):
         _logger.warning('Received mail reply to missing document %s! Ignoring and     creating new document instead for Message-Id %s',
                         thread_id, message_id)
         thread_id = None
     _logger.debug('Routing mail with Message-Id %s: fallback to model:%s, thread_id:%s, custom_values:%s, uid:%s',
                   message_id, model, thread_id, custom_values, uid)
     return [(model, thread_id, custom_values, uid)]
```

Comment: which openerp version are you using?

Comment: and what is the path of the file you're quoting?

Comment: I am working with addons/mail/mail_tread.py
And specifically, the function is at line 284.